# OS X Docker does not set repo name nor tag after build

Tags: macos, docker

On my Ubuntu 14.04 I'm building images from docker file and get correct names after that. But running `docker build -t name .` on OS X 10.10.7 does not set it for repo.

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              1aae5cf19164        5 hours ago         409.9 MB
buildpack-deps      wheezy-scm          1d4e9588f5fc        3 weeks ago         208.7 MB
```

Is it possible due to an error I got at the last step of building an image ?

```
Step 10 : COPY go-wrapper /usr/local/bin/
go-wrapper: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is caused by the error.

while docker build an image from `Dockerfile`, with the initial image [`FROM` defined in `Dockerfile`], it will save the image for every executed command [such as `RUN`, `ADD`, `COPY`, etc] and give each image a `IMAGE ID`, once the image build success, then docker will set the image's repository and tag.

if you want manually set the tag for an image, you can try [docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/tag/) command

Comment: Thanks man, there should some kind of doc about it or message after build, imo